# Odroid Build Fingerprint

Tags: android, fingerprint, odroid

I am using Odroid for one of my Iot projects, but after a few minutes, my app crashes.
I found something in ***adb logcat*** :

[here is image of crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAmb7.png)

any suggestion?

here is tombstone backstack in code:

```
Build fingerprint: 
'ODROID/odroidn2/odroidn2:9/PQ3A.190801.002/20200507:eng/test-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm64'
 pid: 10427, tid: 10432, name: Jit thread pool  >>> PACKAGE NAME <<<
 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20001000080002
 x0  0020001000080002  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000007033a00000  x3  
 0000007033baa240
 x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000007058e008a0  x7  00 
 00000000000000
 x8  491016c172818a42  x9  491016c172818a42  x10 0000000000000001  x11 
0000000000000000
x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000040  x14 0000000000000000  x15 
000000000000002a
x16 00000070dc5b21c8  x17 00000070dc545894  x18 0000000000000000  x19 
0020001000080002
x20 00000070509ab400  x21 0000000000000001  x22 00000070524d2588  x23 
00000070524d20e0
x24 00000070509fc500  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000007058d4b600  x27 
0000000097f2e6e4
x28 0000000097f2e6e0  x29 00000070524d2160
sp  00000070524d1e10  lr  0000007052a365b8  pc  0000007052a365b0

backtrace:
#00 pc 00000000001675b0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so 
(art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, 
art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+2284)
#01 pc 000000000010d1ac  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so ( 
art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, 
bool)+204)
#02 pc 00000000003060c0  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool)+620)
#03 pc 000000000030874c  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+652)
#04 pc 00000000004a9594  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+88)
#05 pc 00000000004a9078  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
#06 pc 00000000000818f8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
#07 pc 0000000000023438  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Comment: It would be nice to have the crash information as a text.